# Different inter-core latency measured on two identical Skylake Xeon Gold 6154 systems

Tags: c, performance, x86-64, intel, avx512

We have been using two same Skylake servers with completely the same softwares, Centos 7 OS and BIOS settings. Everything is the same, except the latency performance. Our software is using AVX512.

In tests, I noticed that AVX512 slows down performance (increasing latency) in the one of the systems each time. There is a significant performance difference. I checked everything, all are the same.

What should I do to solve this problem? Which tool can help?

Thanks in advance..

```
sudo lshw -class cpu
  *-cpu:0                   
       description: CPU
       product: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6154 CPU @ 3.00GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       vendor_id: GenuineIntel
       physical id: 400
       bus info: cpu@0
       version: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6154 CPU @ 3.00GHz
       slot: CPU1
       size: 3GHz
       capacity: 4GHz
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 1010MHz
       capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 intel_ppin intel_pt ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm mpx rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts pku ospke md_clear spec_ctrl intel_stibp flush_l1d
       configuration: cores=18 enabledcores=18 threads=18
  *-cpu:1 DISABLED
       description: CPU [empty]
       physical id: 401
       slot: CPU2
```

**Update:** After Peter's comment(s), I added the following sample code as an example.

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CACHE_LINE_SIZE             64

/**
 * Copy 64 bytes from one location to another,
 * locations should not overlap.
 */
static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) void
mov64(uint8_t *dst, const uint8_t *src)
{
        __m512i zmm0;

        zmm0 = _mm512_load_si512((const void *)src);
        _mm512_store_si512((void *)dst, zmm0);
}

#define likely(x)    __builtin_expect((x), 1)
#define unlikely(x)  __builtin_expect((x), 0)

static inline uint64_t rdtsc(void)
{
    union {
        uint64_t tsc_64;
        __extension__
        struct {
            uint32_t lo_32;
            uint32_t hi_32;
        };
    } tsc;

    __asm__ volatile("rdtsc" :
            "=a" (tsc.lo_32),
            "=d" (tsc.hi_32));
    return tsc.tsc_64;
}
union levels {
    __m512i zmm0;
    struct {
        uint32_t x1;
        uint64_t x2;
        uint64_t x3;
        uint32_t x4;
        uint32_t x5;
        uint32_t x6;
        uint32_t x7;
    };
} __attribute__((aligned(CACHE_LINE_SIZE)));

union levels g_shared;

void *worker_loop(void *param)
{
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(16, &cpuset);

    pthread_t thread = pthread_self();

    pthread_setaffinity_np(thread, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);

    union levels lshared;
    uint32_t old_x1 = 0;
    lshared.x1 = 0;
    while (1) {
        __asm__ ("" ::: "memory");

        lshared.zmm0 = _mm512_load_si512((const void *)&g_shared);

        if (unlikely(lshared.x1 <= old_x1)) {
            continue;
        } else if (unlikely(lshared.x1 != lshared.x7)) {
            // printf("%u %u %u %u %u %u\n", lshared.x1, lshared.x3, lshared.x4, lshared.x5, lshared.x6, lshared.x7);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            uint64_t val = rdtsc();
            if (val > lshared.x2) {
                printf("> (%u) %lu - %lu = %lu\n", lshared.x1, val, lshared.x2, val - lshared.x2);
            } else {
                printf("< (%u) %lu - %lu = %lu\n", lshared.x1, lshared.x2, val, lshared.x2 - val);
            }
        }
        old_x1 = lshared.x1;

        _mm_pause();
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(15, &cpuset);

    pthread_t thread = pthread_self();

    memset(&g_shared, 0, sizeof(g_shared));

    pthread_setaffinity_np(thread, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);

    pthread_t worker;
    pthread_create(&worker, NULL, worker_loop, NULL);

    uint32_t val = 1;
    union levels lshared;

    while (1) {
        lshared.x1 = val;
        lshared.x2 = rdtsc();
        lshared.x3 = val;
        lshared.x4 = val;
        lshared.x5 = val;
        lshared.x6 = val;
        lshared.x7 = val;
        _mm512_store_si512((void *)&g_shared, lshared.zmm0);
        __asm__ ("" ::: "memory");

        usleep(100000);

        val++;

        _mm_pause();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The slower system's output:

```
> (1) 4582365777844442 - 4582365777792564 = 51878
> (2) 4582366077239290 - 4582366077238806 = 484
> (3) 4582366376674782 - 4582366376674346 = 436
> (4) 4582366676044526 - 4582366676041890 = 2636
> (5) 4582366975470562 - 4582366975470134 = 428
> (6) 4582367274899258 - 4582367274898828 = 430
> (7) 4582367574328446 - 4582367574328022 = 424
> (8) 4582367873757956 - 4582367873757532 = 424
> (9) 4582368173187886 - 4582368173187466 = 420
> (10) 4582368472618418 - 4582368472617958 = 460
> (11) 4582368772049720 - 4582368772049236 = 484
> (12) 4582369071481018 - 4582369071480594 = 424
> (13) 4582369370912760 - 4582369370912284 = 476
> (14) 4582369670344890 - 4582369670344212 = 678
> (15) 4582369969776826 - 4582369969776400 = 426
> (16) 4582370269209462 - 4582370269209024 = 438
> (17) 4582370568642626 - 4582370568642172 = 454
> (18) 4582370868076202 - 4582370868075764 = 438
> (19) 4582371167510016 - 4582371167509594 = 422
> (20) 4582371466944326 - 4582371466943892 = 434
> (21) 4582371766379206 - 4582371766378734 = 472
> (22) 4582372065814804 - 4582372065814344 = 460
> (23) 4582372365225608 - 4582372365223068 = 2540
> (24) 4582372664652112 - 4582372664651668 = 444
> (25) 4582372964080746 - 4582372964080314 = 432
> (26) 4582373263510732 - 4582373263510308 = 424
> (27) 4582373562940116 - 4582373562939676 = 440
> (28) 4582373862370284 - 4582373862369860 = 424
> (29) 4582374161800632 - 4582374161800182 = 450
```

The faster system's output:

```
> (1) 9222001841102298 - 9222001841045386 = 56912
> (2) 9222002140513228 - 9222002140512908 = 320
> (3) 9222002439970702 - 9222002439970330 = 372
> (4) 9222002739428448 - 9222002739428114 = 334
> (5) 9222003038886492 - 9222003038886152 = 340
> (6) 9222003338344884 - 9222003338344516 = 368
> (7) 9222003637803702 - 9222003637803332 = 370
> (8) 9222003937262776 - 9222003937262404 = 372
> (9) 9222004236649320 - 9222004236648932 = 388
> (10) 9222004536101876 - 9222004536101510 = 366
> (11) 9222004835554776 - 9222004835554378 = 398
> (12) 9222005135008064 - 9222005135007686 = 378
> (13) 9222005434461868 - 9222005434461526 = 342
> (14) 9222005733916416 - 9222005733916026 = 390
> (15) 9222006033370968 - 9222006033370640 = 328
> (16) 9222006332825872 - 9222006332825484 = 388
> (17) 9222006632280956 - 9222006632280570 = 386
> (18) 9222006931736548 - 9222006931736178 = 370
> (19) 9222007231192376 - 9222007231191986 = 390
> (20) 9222007530648868 - 9222007530648486 = 382
> (21) 9222007830105642 - 9222007830105270 = 372
> (22) 9222008129562750 - 9222008129562382 = 368
> (23) 9222008429020310 - 9222008429019944 = 366
> (24) 9222008728478336 - 9222008728477970 = 366
> (25) 9222009027936696 - 9222009027936298 = 398
> (26) 9222009327395716 - 9222009327395342 = 374
> (27) 9222009626854876 - 9222009626854506 = 370
> (28) 9222009926282324 - 9222009926281936 = 388
> (29) 9222010225734832 - 9222010225734442 = 390
> (30) 9222010525187748 - 9222010525187366 = 382
```

**Update 2:** After Peter's answer, I added the following sample code as an example to measure latency for different mesh network paths on the same die, and the answer's content is true, different cpus have different inter-cpu latency. But still one of the same systems is 25% slower than the other in all case.

Also I don't know if it will affect it, but I just realized that the slow CPU has extra **md_clear** flag.

In conclusion, What should I do to solve this problem? Which tool can help? How can I understand the performance difference?

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CACHE_LINE_SIZE             64

/**
 * Copy 64 bytes from one location to another,
 * locations should not overlap.
 */
static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) void
mov64(uint8_t *dst, const uint8_t *src)
{
        __m512i zmm0;

        zmm0 = _mm512_load_si512((const void *)src);
        _mm512_store_si512((void *)dst, zmm0);
}

#define likely(x)    __builtin_expect((x), 1)
#define unlikely(x)  __builtin_expect((x), 0)

static inline uint64_t rdtsc(void)
{
    union {
        uint64_t tsc_64;
        __extension__
        struct {
            uint32_t lo_32;
            uint32_t hi_32;
        };
    } tsc;

    __asm__ volatile("rdtsc" :
            "=a" (tsc.lo_32),
            "=d" (tsc.hi_32));
    return tsc.tsc_64;
}
union levels {
    __m512i zmm0;
    struct {
        uint32_t x1;
        uint64_t x2;
        uint64_t x3;
        uint32_t x4;
        uint32_t x5;
        uint32_t x6;
        uint32_t x7;
    };
} __attribute__((aligned(CACHE_LINE_SIZE)));

union levels g_shared;

uint32_t g_main_cpu;
uint32_t g_worker_cpu;

void *worker_loop(void *param)
{
    _mm_mfence();

    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(g_worker_cpu, &cpuset);

    pthread_t thread = pthread_self();

    pthread_setaffinity_np(thread, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);

    union levels lshared;
    uint32_t old_x1 = 1;

    uint64_t min = 10000, max = 0, sum = 0;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 300) {
        __asm__ ("" ::: "memory");
        lshared.zmm0 = _mm512_load_si512((const void *)&g_shared);

        if (unlikely(lshared.x1 <= old_x1)) {
            continue;
        } else if (unlikely(lshared.x1 != lshared.x7)) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            uint64_t val = rdtsc();
            uint64_t diff = val - lshared.x2;
            sum += diff;
            if (min > diff)
                min = diff;

            if (diff > max)
                max = diff;

            i++;
        }
        old_x1 = lshared.x1;

        _mm_pause();
    }

    printf("(M=%u-W=%u) min=%lu max=%lu mean=%lu\n", g_main_cpu, g_worker_cpu, min, max, sum / 300);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int main_cpu = 2; main_cpu <= 17; ++main_cpu) {
        for (int worker_cpu = 2; worker_cpu <= 17; ++worker_cpu) {
            if (main_cpu == worker_cpu) {
                continue;
            }
            _mm_mfence();

            g_main_cpu = main_cpu;
            g_worker_cpu = worker_cpu;

            cpu_set_t cpuset;
            CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
            CPU_SET(g_main_cpu, &cpuset);

            pthread_t thread = pthread_self();

            memset(&g_shared, 0, sizeof(g_shared));

            pthread_setaffinity_np(thread, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);

            pthread_t worker;
            pthread_create(&worker, NULL, worker_loop, NULL);

            uint32_t val = 0;
            union levels lshared;

            for (int i = 0; i < 350; ++i) {
                lshared.x1 = val;
                lshared.x2 = rdtsc();
                lshared.x3 = val;
                lshared.x4 = val;
                lshared.x5 = val;
                lshared.x6 = val;
                lshared.x7 = val;
                _mm512_store_si512((void *)&g_shared, lshared.zmm0);
                __asm__ ("" ::: "memory");

                usleep(100000);

                val++;

                _mm_pause();
            }

            pthread_join(worker, NULL);
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Both system's output: (2-17 are isolated cpus)

```
            slow cpu    fast cpu
------------------------------------                

(M=2-W=3)   mean=580    mean=374
(M=2-W=4)   mean=463    mean=365
(M=2-W=5)   mean=449    mean=391
(M=2-W=6)   mean=484    mean=345
(M=2-W=7)   mean=430    mean=386
(M=2-W=8)   mean=439    mean=369
(M=2-W=9)   mean=445    mean=376
(M=2-W=10)  mean=480    mean=354
(M=2-W=11)  mean=440    mean=392
(M=2-W=12)  mean=475    mean=324
(M=2-W=13)  mean=453    mean=373
(M=2-W=14)  mean=474    mean=344
(M=2-W=15)  mean=445    mean=384
(M=2-W=16)  mean=468    mean=372
(M=2-W=17)  mean=462    mean=373
(M=3-W=2)   mean=447    mean=392
(M=3-W=4)   mean=556    mean=386
(M=3-W=5)   mean=418    mean=409
(M=3-W=6)   mean=473    mean=372
(M=3-W=7)   mean=397    mean=400
(M=3-W=8)   mean=408    mean=403
(M=3-W=9)   mean=412    mean=413
(M=3-W=10)  mean=447    mean=389
(M=3-W=11)  mean=412    mean=423
(M=3-W=12)  mean=446    mean=399
(M=3-W=13)  mean=427    mean=407
(M=3-W=14)  mean=445    mean=390
(M=3-W=15)  mean=417    mean=448
(M=3-W=16)  mean=438    mean=386
(M=3-W=17)  mean=435    mean=396
(M=4-W=2)   mean=463    mean=368
(M=4-W=3)   mean=433    mean=401
(M=4-W=5)   mean=561    mean=406
(M=4-W=6)   mean=468    mean=378
(M=4-W=7)   mean=416    mean=387
(M=4-W=8)   mean=425    mean=386
(M=4-W=9)   mean=425    mean=415
(M=4-W=10)  mean=464    mean=379
(M=4-W=11)  mean=424    mean=404
(M=4-W=12)  mean=456    mean=369
(M=4-W=13)  mean=441    mean=395
(M=4-W=14)  mean=460    mean=378
(M=4-W=15)  mean=427    mean=405
(M=4-W=16)  mean=446    mean=369
(M=4-W=17)  mean=448    mean=391
(M=5-W=2)   mean=447    mean=382
(M=5-W=3)   mean=418    mean=406
(M=5-W=4)   mean=430    mean=397
(M=5-W=6)   mean=584    mean=386
(M=5-W=7)   mean=399    mean=399
(M=5-W=8)   mean=404    mean=386
(M=5-W=9)   mean=408    mean=408
(M=5-W=10)  mean=446    mean=378
(M=5-W=11)  mean=411    mean=407
(M=5-W=12)  mean=440    mean=385
(M=5-W=13)  mean=424    mean=402
(M=5-W=14)  mean=442    mean=381
(M=5-W=15)  mean=411    mean=411
(M=5-W=16)  mean=433    mean=398
(M=5-W=17)  mean=429    mean=395
(M=6-W=2)   mean=486    mean=356
(M=6-W=3)   mean=453    mean=388
(M=6-W=4)   mean=471    mean=353
(M=6-W=5)   mean=452    mean=388
(M=6-W=7)   mean=570    mean=360
(M=6-W=8)   mean=444    mean=377
(M=6-W=9)   mean=450    mean=376
(M=6-W=10)  mean=485    mean=335
(M=6-W=11)  mean=451    mean=410
(M=6-W=12)  mean=479    mean=353
(M=6-W=13)  mean=463    mean=363
(M=6-W=14)  mean=479    mean=359
(M=6-W=15)  mean=450    mean=394
(M=6-W=16)  mean=473    mean=364
(M=6-W=17)  mean=469    mean=373
(M=7-W=2)   mean=454    mean=365
(M=7-W=3)   mean=418    mean=410
(M=7-W=4)   mean=443    mean=370
(M=7-W=5)   mean=421    mean=407
(M=7-W=6)   mean=456    mean=363
(M=7-W=8)   mean=527    mean=380
(M=7-W=9)   mean=417    mean=392
(M=7-W=10)  mean=460    mean=361
(M=7-W=11)  mean=421    mean=402
(M=7-W=12)  mean=447    mean=354
(M=7-W=13)  mean=430    mean=381
(M=7-W=14)  mean=449    mean=375
(M=7-W=15)  mean=420    mean=393
(M=7-W=16)  mean=442    mean=352
(M=7-W=17)  mean=438    mean=367
(M=8-W=2)   mean=463    mean=382
(M=8-W=3)   mean=434    mean=411
(M=8-W=4)   mean=452    mean=372
(M=8-W=5)   mean=429    mean=402
(M=8-W=6)   mean=469    mean=368
(M=8-W=7)   mean=416    mean=418
(M=8-W=9)   mean=560    mean=418
(M=8-W=10)  mean=468    mean=385
(M=8-W=11)  mean=429    mean=394
(M=8-W=12)  mean=460    mean=378
(M=8-W=13)  mean=439    mean=392
(M=8-W=14)  mean=459    mean=373
(M=8-W=15)  mean=429    mean=383
(M=8-W=16)  mean=452    mean=376
(M=8-W=17)  mean=449    mean=401
(M=9-W=2)   mean=440    mean=368
(M=9-W=3)   mean=410    mean=398
(M=9-W=4)   mean=426    mean=385
(M=9-W=5)   mean=406    mean=403
(M=9-W=6)   mean=447    mean=378
(M=9-W=7)   mean=393    mean=427
(M=9-W=8)   mean=408    mean=368
(M=9-W=10)  mean=580    mean=392
(M=9-W=11)  mean=408    mean=387
(M=9-W=12)  mean=433    mean=381
(M=9-W=13)  mean=418    mean=444
(M=9-W=14)  mean=441    mean=407
(M=9-W=15)  mean=408    mean=401
(M=9-W=16)  mean=427    mean=376
(M=9-W=17)  mean=426    mean=383
(M=10-W=2)  mean=478    mean=361
(M=10-W=3)  mean=446    mean=379
(M=10-W=4)  mean=461    mean=350
(M=10-W=5)  mean=445    mean=373
(M=10-W=6)  mean=483    mean=354
(M=10-W=7)  mean=428    mean=370
(M=10-W=8)  mean=436    mean=355
(M=10-W=9)  mean=448    mean=390
(M=10-W=11) mean=569    mean=350
(M=10-W=12) mean=473    mean=337
(M=10-W=13) mean=454    mean=370
(M=10-W=14) mean=474    mean=360
(M=10-W=15) mean=441    mean=370
(M=10-W=16) mean=463    mean=354
(M=10-W=17) mean=462    mean=358
(M=11-W=2)  mean=447    mean=384
(M=11-W=3)  mean=411    mean=408
(M=11-W=4)  mean=433    mean=394
(M=11-W=5)  mean=413    mean=428
(M=11-W=6)  mean=455    mean=383
(M=11-W=7)  mean=402    mean=395
(M=11-W=8)  mean=407    mean=418
(M=11-W=9)  mean=417    mean=424
(M=11-W=10) mean=452    mean=395
(M=11-W=12) mean=577    mean=406
(M=11-W=13) mean=426    mean=402
(M=11-W=14) mean=442    mean=412
(M=11-W=15) mean=408    mean=411
(M=11-W=16) mean=435    mean=400
(M=11-W=17) mean=431    mean=415
(M=12-W=2)  mean=473    mean=352
(M=12-W=3)  mean=447    mean=381
(M=12-W=4)  mean=461    mean=361
(M=12-W=5)  mean=445    mean=366
(M=12-W=6)  mean=483    mean=322
(M=12-W=7)  mean=431    mean=358
(M=12-W=8)  mean=438    mean=340
(M=12-W=9)  mean=448    mean=409
(M=12-W=10) mean=481    mean=334
(M=12-W=11) mean=447    mean=351
(M=12-W=13) mean=580    mean=383
(M=12-W=14) mean=473    mean=359
(M=12-W=15) mean=441    mean=385
(M=12-W=16) mean=463    mean=355
(M=12-W=17) mean=462    mean=358
(M=13-W=2)  mean=450    mean=385
(M=13-W=3)  mean=420    mean=410
(M=13-W=4)  mean=440    mean=396
(M=13-W=5)  mean=418    mean=402
(M=13-W=6)  mean=461    mean=385
(M=13-W=7)  mean=406    mean=391
(M=13-W=8)  mean=415    mean=382
(M=13-W=9)  mean=421    mean=402
(M=13-W=10) mean=457    mean=376
(M=13-W=11) mean=422    mean=409
(M=13-W=12) mean=451    mean=381
(M=13-W=14) mean=579    mean=375
(M=13-W=15) mean=430    mean=402
(M=13-W=16) mean=440    mean=408
(M=13-W=17) mean=439    mean=394
(M=14-W=2)  mean=477    mean=330
(M=14-W=3)  mean=449    mean=406
(M=14-W=4)  mean=464    mean=355
(M=14-W=5)  mean=450    mean=389
(M=14-W=6)  mean=487    mean=342
(M=14-W=7)  mean=432    mean=380
(M=14-W=8)  mean=439    mean=360
(M=14-W=9)  mean=451    mean=405
(M=14-W=10) mean=485    mean=356
(M=14-W=11) mean=447    mean=398
(M=14-W=12) mean=479    mean=338
(M=14-W=13) mean=455    mean=382
(M=14-W=15) mean=564    mean=383
(M=14-W=16) mean=481    mean=361
(M=14-W=17) mean=465    mean=351
(M=15-W=2)  mean=426    mean=409
(M=15-W=3)  mean=395    mean=424
(M=15-W=4)  mean=412    mean=427
(M=15-W=5)  mean=395    mean=425
(M=15-W=6)  mean=435    mean=391
(M=15-W=7)  mean=379    mean=405
(M=15-W=8)  mean=388    mean=412
(M=15-W=9)  mean=399    mean=432
(M=15-W=10) mean=432    mean=389
(M=15-W=11) mean=397    mean=432
(M=15-W=12) mean=426    mean=393
(M=15-W=13) mean=404    mean=407
(M=15-W=14) mean=429    mean=412
(M=15-W=16) mean=539    mean=391
(M=15-W=17) mean=414    mean=397
(M=16-W=2)  mean=456    mean=368
(M=16-W=3)  mean=422    mean=406
(M=16-W=4)  mean=445    mean=384
(M=16-W=5)  mean=427    mean=397
(M=16-W=6)  mean=462    mean=348
(M=16-W=7)  mean=413    mean=408
(M=16-W=8)  mean=419    mean=361
(M=16-W=9)  mean=429    mean=385
(M=16-W=10) mean=463    mean=369
(M=16-W=11) mean=426    mean=404
(M=16-W=12) mean=454    mean=391
(M=16-W=13) mean=434    mean=378
(M=16-W=14) mean=454    mean=412
(M=16-W=15) mean=424    mean=416
(M=16-W=17) mean=578    mean=378
(M=17-W=2)  mean=460    mean=402
(M=17-W=3)  mean=419    mean=381
(M=17-W=4)  mean=446    mean=394
(M=17-W=5)  mean=424    mean=422
(M=17-W=6)  mean=468    mean=369
(M=17-W=7)  mean=409    mean=401
(M=17-W=8)  mean=418    mean=405
(M=17-W=9)  mean=428    mean=414
(M=17-W=10) mean=459    mean=369
(M=17-W=11) mean=424    mean=387
(M=17-W=12) mean=451    mean=372
(M=17-W=13) mean=435    mean=382
(M=17-W=14) mean=459    mean=369
(M=17-W=15) mean=426    mean=401
(M=17-W=16) mean=446    mean=371
```

Comment: Can you explain in words what your microbenchmark is measuring?  I think inter-thread latency, but you're pinning to some specific cores?  You're spinning on a load and branch, it seems, without `_mm_pause()`?  I guess `barrier()` is something like `asm("":::"memory")` but you don't show a definition.

Comment: @PeterCordes for this example, I'm trying to measure inter-cpu latency. Even this shows me a proof of slowness, the systems are exactly the same In the real code, I'm using SIMD/AVX512 for math operations as well and in the field working application, there is an incredible difference for the same systems. How can this happen? barrier is asm("":::"memory").

Comment: Both of those things would be good edits for the question.

Comment: Ok, `_mm_pause()` just made both versions about the same amount slower, I think.  That's good, I guess.  Is the `continue;` in the reader ever reached?  That skips the `pause`.  But I think that's not where it spends most of its time waiting; I didn't take the time to fully sort out that logic and there are no comments.

Comment: IMO you should be showing the *median*, not mean.  Your results all had huge spikes on the first iteration (cold cache, thread startup?) which you shouldn't be counting.  And occasional other spikes, probably from interrupts or other contention.

Comment: The code ignores the first iteration, so the mean is ok. I exceeded the maximum character limit, so I had to remove the other parts.

Comment: There are still a few spikes like 2540 mixed in with the 430 +- 15 or so numbers in your first output.  I'd print the mean + minimum at least (because that's easy), and ideally the median. You don't really need 2 copies of your source code in the question.  You could shortlink to https://godbolt.org/ for one of them, or link to a previous revision of your question for the original version.  But I guess it's basically fine the way it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**My guess**: different [Xeon Gold 6154](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/120495/intel-xeon-gold-6154-processor-24-75m-cache-3-00-ghz.html) chips (18c 36t) have **different cores fused off** for defects, so you have a **different mesh network path** between the two cores you pin to and/or the slice of L3 cache that your cache line ends up being mapped to.  This affects the inter-core latency between those two cores.

According to Wikichip, it's [based on the "Extreme Core Count die" for SKX](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/Category:microprocessor_models_by_intel_based_on_skylake_extreme_core_count_die), which has 28 physical cores on it, the core count of the [Xeon Platinum 8176](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/xeon_platinum/8176) based on the same die.

So 10 cores are disabled on your die, but possibly a different 10.  This can mean some of the cores are more hops away from each other (maybe)?  And/or it could mean cores are enumerated in a different order so same hard-coded core numbers mean different mesh locations.

https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/mesh_interconnect_architecture

---

**Your update shows new data from all pairs of cores.**  It seems one CPU is slower for most but not all pairs.  (Although I don't fully trust that data if you're using the mean without discarding outliers.)  That's still plausibly explained by a different mesh layout, possibly with significantly worse distances between most cores.

It's a 2D mesh presumably mirroring the physical layout of the cores.  Maybe the fast CPU mostly has cores around the outside disabled so the active ones are fairly densely packed into a smaller grid.  But maybe the slower one had defects in more "interior" cores in the grid.

> I just realized that the slow CPU has extra `md_clear` CPU feature flag.

According to https://software.intel.com/security-software-guidance/insights/deep-dive-intel-analysis-microarchitectural-data-sampling, the `md_clear` flag indicates microcode support for workarounds for L1TF / microarchitectural data sampling via the `verw` instruction, etc.

Perhaps the newer microcode version also has an another change that hurts performance in this microbenchmark (and maybe overall).  Or maybe that's a coincidence.

More data from more Xeon Gold CPUs with older vs. newer microcode might shed some light.  If we still see this much variation between CPUs even with identical microcode, that would support my hypothesis that it's a consequence of which physical cores are fused off to sell as 28-core die as an 18-working-core CPU.

Also testing on a Xeon based on a smaller die, like the 14-core HCC die with all 14 cores enabled, might show better worst-case-pair inter-core latency.  Might need to control for different RDTSC vs turbo vs uncore frequencies, unless the mesh clock scales with reference core clock.

---

**That explanation doesn't depend on AVX512 at all.  Do you see the same effect with scalar loads or not?**

<s>Also, possibly a small timing difference happens to have a worse effect on one than the other without `_mm_pause`; maybe one core is seeing a pipeline nuke (`machine_clears.memory_ordering` perf event) and the other isn't?</s>

Your update with `_mm_pause()` mostly rules out amplifying a small difference in true latency.  Whatever the cause is, the difference does seem to be that big.

---

Your CPU is new enough that it's safe to assume that the TSC is synced between cores, and presumably that both are already running at max turbo.  (One of the named CPU features, `constant_tsc` or `invariant_tsc` explicitly guarantees that, but I forget which one.  The other one means it ticks at a fixed reference frequency regardless of the core clock frequency.  `nonstop_tsc` means it doesn't stop when the core is asleep.)

(TL:DR: I think your microbenchmark looks sane, and you are measuring inter-core latency in a reasonable way, without huge measurement error.)

---

> What should I do to solve this problem?

You can't.

If low inter-core latency is critical for one application, try a few different CPUs until you find one with lower latencies than average.

Run other applications on the Xeons with worse latency.

Or if my hypothesis is right, maybe get a 14-core Xeon Gold based on the High Core Count die.  With all 14 cores enabled, that should be best case.  But those Xeons only have 1 AVX512 FMA unit.

> Which tool can help?

If there are only a few threads that need tight coupling, find a cluster of physical cores that have the lowest latency from each other on the CPU you have.  Pin the most latency-sensitive threads to those cores.

If that works for your application, **maybe consider a Zen or Zen2 microarchitecture based on CCX units of 4 physical cores with low latency inside that cluster**, but significantly worse latency across clusters.  AMD does have some many-core chips, but only Zen2 has full 256-bit SIMD width in its load/store and execution units.  (It still doesn't do AVX512, but if your application can make heavy use of SIMD then at least full-speed AVX2+FMA is probably what you want).

> How can I understand the performance difference?

If my hypothesis is correct, it's an intrinsic property of the CPU as manufactured and sold.  Intel designs a die with `n` physical cores.  If manufacturing defects ruin some of those cores, they can still sell it as a lower core-count SKU.  (They burn away a physical fuse so the disabled core doesn't waste power).  Presumably its mesh node still has to work, unless they can short-circuit past a whole node to tighten up the mesh?

When yields are above demand for the highest core-count SKUs at the price-point they want to sell at, they will disable some working cores as well as defective cores on a chip.  But this is usually physical with a laser fuse, not just firmware like in old GPUs where you could sometimes just hack the firmware to activate the disabled cores.  So there's nothing you can actually do about it.

Buying a chip with all cores on die enabled (e.g. 28 cores for the "Extreme" core count Xeons) would mean no fused-off cores.  That might give us some interesting test data as far as worst-case pair for inter-core latency.

**A lower core-count die with all the cores enabled might also be interesting.**  The https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/Category:microprocessor_models_by_intel_based_on_skylake_high_core_count_die page shows the "high" core count (HCC) SKX die has 14 cores (half the ECC die).  The top model using that die is [Xeon Gold 5120](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/xeon_gold/5120), a 14c/28t model.  (With 1x 512-bit FMA unit per core, not 2).  [Intel Ark confirms](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/120474/intel-xeon-gold-5120-processor-19-25m-cache-2-20-ghz.html).

I wouldn't be surprised if the HCC die only has 1 FMA unit per core, unlike the ECC die which includes the extra port-5 512-bit FMA unit.  That would save die area for all the mid-range SKUs Intel sells, and having a 2nd FMA unit only helps for AVX512 code.  A lot of code doesn't make any use of AVX512.  (AVX2 and AVX512 256-bit FMA throughput is still 2/clock on port 0 / port 1 on those CPUs.)

Comment: @PeterCorder The content is true, different cpus have different inter-cpu latency. But still one of the same systems is 25% slower than the other in all case. I updated the question according to your answer.

Comment: @AliVolkanATLI: updated with some ideas.  IDK if the microcode version difference is significant.  Maybe try installing the `intel-microcode` package in your Linux distro so that both your CPUs get updated to the same latest microcode on each boot.  (You can always remove it again and reboot if it makes your fast CPU slower.  And if you read the release notes and decide there aren't any critical-for-you CPU bug fixes you'd be missing.  e.g. local side-channel vulnerabilities might not be relevant if you trust all the users with access.)

Comment: @PeterCorder, I think, It depends on AVX512 because I don't see the same effect with scalar loads. The measured values are similar without AVX512.

Comment: @AliVolkanATLI - that makes me suspicious of microcode.  Maybe full-cache-line stores can use some special optimization like skipping an RFO.  But maybe microcode disabled that after finding a bug of some sort?  Or maybe full-line stores are affected differently by mesh topology for some reason, so my hypothesis might still be valid.

Comment: you were right, I just updated the slow system's microcode and now the measured results are almost similar.

Comment: @ali oh perfect, I was assuming ucode update would slow down the faster system

Comment: I did not touch the faster system, I updated the slower, they are still not the same but it seems there was a problem in the intermediate version